# how to filter json data by json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

For example, there is JSON data:

```json
{
  "aa": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "2"
  }
}
```

And there is JSON schema:

```json
{
  "aa": {
    "required": true,
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it there any tools that could filter the JSON data and put extra field into "_extra" using the schema and provide following JSON as an output:

```json
{
  "aa": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "2"
  },
  "_extra": {
    "aa": {
      "b": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Then i can put it into es

Comment: JSON schema is for a validation only, you can not use it for filtering or something else.

Comment: It seems i have to hardcode, that's too bad

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly old library, and it doesn't fully do what you need with the '_extra' requirement, but it could at least filter out the data that is not covered by the schema:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-filter

You could then use something similar to the following package to pick out the differences:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff